# Are circular waves on a lake just the borders of a “bubble”?

Tags: waves, laws-of-physics

When you throw a rock on a lake it makes circular visible waves. Can it be that the rock causes a “expansive bubble” underwater that we can only see its borders on the surface?

Like the bubble made of the impact from Matrix Revolution fight scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are [surface gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave).  The magnitude of the motion decays exponentially with depth, $y$, into the water as $exp(-2\pi y/\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength.  
In contrast, [semicircular traveling vortices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnbJEg9r1o8) can be created that have properties somewhat along the lines you are thinking.

Comment: By comparison, an underwater explosion can cause a spherical shock wave, tho' again funny things happen when a portion of that wave reaches the surface .

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft Good point.  Even just throwing a stone in, there will be accoustic compression waves that expands spherically at 340 m/s in the air and 1481 m/s in the water. I supose these must both create some tiny vertical displacements where they intersect the surface.